# How to use ng-if in ng-repeat to apply css class

Tags: css, angularjs

I am trying to add a class to my tr on my valid condition like if daydate is "Sunday" Only the I would like to add class "red-text"

```
<tr ng-repeat="atten in attendList.attendance" ng-if="atten.daydate == 'Sunday'" class="red-text">
                <td class="custom-icon-size text-font" style="border-left: 1px solid #e8eaf6;" >{{ atten.attenDate }}</td>
                <td class="custom-icon-size text-font" style="border-left: 1px solid #e8eaf6;">{{ atten.daydate }}</td>
                <td class="custom-icon-size text-font" style="border-left: 1px solid #e8eaf6;">{{ atten.intime }}</td>
                <td class="custom-icon-size text-font" style="border-left: 1px solid #e8eaf6;">{{ atten.outtime }}</td>
            </tr>
```

But Unable to get the result

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove ng-if & use ng-class like this

```
ng-class="{'red-text': atten.daydate == 'Sunday'}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need ng-if at all to make it work.

```
ng-class={'red-text': atten.daydate === 'Sunday'}
```

You can also add more items to ng-class for other days if you want like this:

```
ng-class={'red-text': attendaydate === 'Sunday', 'blue-text': 'attendaydate === 'Monday', 'green-text': attendaydate === 'Tuesday'}
```

ng-if is not needed at all as the classes will only be applied based on the truthiness of the statements you are providing to ng-class properties.